# How to replace the sound coming through the microphone? OS X

Tags: macos, bash, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I want to learn how to replace the sound coming through the microphone, such as voice. So that in other programs using the microphone, input are already coming spoofed me sound. Sound is necessary to replace in real time. I will play with the transformation of the voice.

I can not understand in what direction should I google. Can it be done only by XCode, or need any bash script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
This question has nothing for us to go off of. Research is key

Comment: I would suggest understanding the different between Xcode (IDE) and bash shell scripting would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input device to something other than your computer's microphone or import an audio file, depending on the program you're using.